# 'get_attribute' in Selenium Python

Tags: python, selenium, web-scraping

I’ve been trying to scrape *https://www.uniqlo.com/tw/zh_TW/women_tops_long-and-3-4sleeves-and-cardigan.html* using Selenium.

```
driver.get('https://www.uniqlo.com/tw/zh_TW/c/ALL020000024.html')

WebDriverWait(driver, 30, 0.5).until(
    EC.presence_of_element_located((By.CLASS_NAME, 'picture-img')))

time.sleep(20)
a = driver.find_elements(By.CLASS_NAME, 'product-li')
print("a: ",a,"\n")
results = []
```

It has 20 products that we want.
And we want to find the detail information of these products.

So we use *get_attribute*:

```
for x in a:
    time.sleep(10)
    src = x.find_element(By.CLASS_NAME, 'picture-img').get_attribute('src')
    alt = x.find_element(By.CLASS_NAME, 'picture-img').get_attribute('alt')
    print("src: ",src )
    print("alt: ",alt)
    result = {
        'src': src,
        'slt': alt,
    }
    results.append(result)
```

But the loop break down. It only get the 1 to 8 products' attribute.

There are actually 20 elements in list a. Why do we only get some of the attributes, not all of them?

[Enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9tc4E.png)

Comment: what data are you after. You can get ton of info from the data source directly in a nice json format

Comment: are you just after the picture/image link?

Comment: @chitown88 We want the products' image link and other info like price and colors

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just get the data straight from the source:

```python
import requests
from datetime import datetime
import pandas as pd

url = 'https://www.uniqlo.com/tw/zh_TW/data/pages/women_tops_long-and-3-4sleeves-and-cardigan.html.json'
headers = {'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/96.0.4664.93 Safari/537.36'
    }
payload = {
    't':str(int(datetime.now().timestamp()))}
jsonData = requests.get(url, headers=headers, params=payload).json()

items = jsonData['section08']['props']['items']
basic_info_df = pd.DataFrame(items)

rows = []
for productCode in list(basic_info_df['productCode']):
    print(productCode)
    url = f'https://www.uniqlo.com/tw/data/products/prodInfo/zh_TW/{productCode}.json'
    jsonData = requests.get(url, headers=headers).json()

    rows.append(jsonData)

full_df = pd.DataFrame(rows)
```

**Output:**

```python
print(full_df.to_string())
```

```
    originPrice   score inactive                                           mainPic minSize stock hasStock gDeptValue priceColor                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                 colorList evaluationCount  minPrice                                           name  maxPrice    code maxSize enabledFlag             identity approval sex                                                 fullName              label timeLimitedBegin     productCode timeLimitedEnd
0         990.0     0.0        N  /hmall/test/u0000000011533/main/first/1000/1.jpg       S     Y        Y         女裝      black                                                                                                                                                                                                                                          [{'styleText': '01 OFF WHITE', 'colorNo': 'COL01'}, {'styleText': '06 GRAY', 'colorNo': 'COL06'}, {'styleText': '09 BLACK', 'colorNo': 'COL09'}]               0     990.0                                  特級彈性DRY T恤 +S     990.0  447126      XL           Y        [new_product]     LIST  女裝                                  女裝 特級彈性DRY T恤 +S 447126        new_product                   u0000000011533
1         590.0     0.0        N  /hmall/test/u0000000011620/main/first/1000/1.jpg      XS     Y        Y         女裝      black                                  [{'styleText': '01 OFF WHITE', 'colorNo': 'COL01'}, {'styleText': '08 DARK GRAY', 'colorNo': 'COL08'}, {'styleText': '09 BLACK', 'colorNo': 'COL09'}, {'styleText': '10 PINK', 'colorNo': 'COL10'}, {'styleText': '30 NATURAL', 'colorNo': 'COL30'}, {'styleText': '50 LIGHT GREE', 'colorNo': 'COL50'}, {'styleText': '71 PURPLE', 'colorNo': 'COL71'}]               0     590.0                                    華夫格圓領T恤(長袖)     590.0  444514     3XL           Y        [new_product]     LIST  女裝                                    女裝 華夫格圓領T恤(長袖) 444514        new_product                   u0000000011620
2         790.0     5.0        N  /hmall/test/u0000000011478/main/first/1000/1.jpg      XS     Y        Y         女裝      black                                                                                                                                                                                          [{'styleText': '01 OFF WHITE', 'colorNo': 'COL01'}, {'styleText': '09 BLACK', 'colorNo': 'COL09'}, {'styleText': '41 YELLOW', 'colorNo': 'COL41'}, {'styleText': '62 BLUE', 'colorNo': 'COL62'}]               1     790.0                                   圓領短版休閒上衣(長袖)     790.0  444533     3XL           Y        [new_product]     LIST  女裝                                   女裝 圓領短版休閒上衣(長袖) 444533        new_product                   u0000000011478
3         590.0     0.0        N  /hmall/test/u0000000011503/main/first/1000/1.jpg      XS     Y        Y         女裝      black                                                                                                                                                                                           [{'styleText': '01 OFF WHITE', 'colorNo': 'COL01'}, {'styleText': '42 YELLOW', 'colorNo': 'COL42'}, {'styleText': '65 BLUE', 'colorNo': 'COL65'}, {'styleText': '69 NAVY', 'colorNo': 'COL69'}]               0     590.0                                   女裝條紋寬版T恤(長袖)     590.0  444516     3XL           Y        [new_product]     LIST  女裝                                   女裝 女裝條紋寬版T恤(長袖) 444516        new_product                   u0000000011503
4         790.0  4.6316        N                                               NaN       S     Y        Y         女裝        red                                                                                      [{'styleText': '00 WHITE', 'colorNo': 'COL00'}, {'styleText': '08 DARK GRAY', 'colorNo': 'COL08'}, {'styleText': '09 BLACK', 'colorNo': 'COL09'}, {'styleText': '30 NATURAL', 'colorNo': 'COL30'}, {'styleText': '58 DARK GREEN', 'colorNo': 'COL58'}, {'styleText': '68 BLUE', 'colorNo': 'COL68'}]              19     390.0                          HEATTECH棉質 中高領T恤 (長袖)     390.0  441587     3XL           Y  [concessional_rate]     LIST  女裝                          女裝 HEATTECH棉質 中高領T恤 (長袖) 441587  concessional_rate                   u0000000010558
5         590.0  4.3636        N  /hmall/test/u0000000010146/main/first/1000/1.jpg      XS     Y        Y         女裝      black                                                                                                                                                                                             [{'styleText': '01 OFF WHITE', 'colorNo': 'COL01'}, {'styleText': '17 RED', 'colorNo': 'COL17'}, {'styleText': '34 BROWN', 'colorNo': 'COL34'}, {'styleText': '69 NAVY', 'colorNo': 'COL69'}]              11     590.0                                    條紋寬版T恤 (長袖)     590.0  442793     3XL           Y      [EXTENDED SIZE]     LIST  女裝                                    女裝 條紋寬版T恤 (長袖) 442793      EXTENDED SIZE                   u0000000010146
6        4990.0  3.3333        N  /hmall/test/u0000000011297/main/first/1000/1.jpg      XS     Y        Y         女裝      black                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                        [{'styleText': '08 DARK GRAY', 'colorNo': 'COL08'}, {'styleText': '09 BLACK', 'colorNo': 'COL09'}]               3    4990.0                                 +J 絲質領結上衣 (長袖)    4990.0  446290     XXL           Y      [EXTENDED SIZE]     LIST  女裝                                 女裝 +J 絲質領結上衣 (長袖) 446290      EXTENDED SIZE                   u0000000011297
7        4990.0     5.0        N  /hmall/test/u0000000011257/main/first/1000/1.jpg      XS     Y        Y         女裝      black                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                           [{'styleText': '34 BROWN', 'colorNo': 'COL34'}, {'styleText': '76 PURPLE', 'colorNo': 'COL76'}]               1    4990.0                                   +J 絲質上衣 (長袖)    4990.0  446577     XXL           Y      [EXTENDED SIZE]     LIST  女裝                                   女裝 +J 絲質上衣 (長袖) 446577      EXTENDED SIZE                   u0000000011257
8         990.0  4.6667        N  /hmall/test/u0000000011030/main/first/1000/1.jpg      XS     Y        Y         女裝        red                                                                                                                                                                                          [{'styleText': '01 OFF WHITE', 'colorNo': 'COL01'}, {'styleText': '09 BLACK', 'colorNo': 'COL09'}, {'styleText': '31 BEIGE', 'colorNo': 'COL31'}, {'styleText': '57 OLIVE', 'colorNo': 'COL57'}]              15     490.0  White Mountaineering 刷毛寬版中高領上衣 (長袖) (品牌好友穿著款)     490.0  443226     3XL           Y  [concessional_rate]     LIST  女裝  女裝 White Mountaineering 刷毛寬版中高領上衣 (長袖) (品牌好友穿著款) 443226  concessional_rate                   u0000000011030
9         590.0   4.963        N                                               NaN      XS     Y        Y         女裝      black                                              [{'styleText': '01 OFF WHITE', 'colorNo': 'COL01'}, {'styleText': '03 GRAY', 'colorNo': 'COL03'}, {'styleText': '09 BLACK', 'colorNo': 'COL09'}, {'styleText': '31 BEIGE', 'colorNo': 'COL31'}, {'styleText': '32 BEIGE', 'colorNo': 'COL32'}, {'styleText': '65 BLUE', 'colorNo': 'COL65'}, {'styleText': '78 PURPLE', 'colorNo': 'COL78'}]              27     590.0                              柔軟針織圓領 泡芙袖T恤 (長袖)     590.0  439142     3XL           Y      [EXTENDED SIZE]     LIST  女裝                              女裝 柔軟針織圓領 泡芙袖T恤 (長袖) 439142      EXTENDED SIZE                   u0000000010990
10        590.0     4.6        N  /hmall/test/u0000000011073/main/first/1000/1.jpg      XS     Y        Y         女裝      black                                                                                         [{'styleText': '01 OFF WHITE', 'colorNo': 'COL01'}, {'styleText': '08 DARK GRAY', 'colorNo': 'COL08'}, {'styleText': '09 BLACK', 'colorNo': 'COL09'}, {'styleText': '12 PINK', 'colorNo': 'COL12'}, {'styleText': '68 BLUE', 'colorNo': 'COL68'}, {'styleText': '76 PURPLE', 'colorNo': 'COL76'}]               5     590.0                         HEATTECH 彈性刷毛圓領T恤 (長袖)     590.0  440267     3XL           Y      [EXTENDED SIZE]     LIST  女裝                         女裝 HEATTECH 彈性刷毛圓領T恤 (長袖) 440267      EXTENDED SIZE                   u0000000011073
11        590.0     4.4        N  /hmall/test/u0000000011100/main/first/1000/1.jpg      XS     Y        Y         女裝      black  [{'styleText': '01 OFF WHITE', 'colorNo': 'COL01'}, {'styleText': '07 GRAY', 'colorNo': 'COL07'}, {'styleText': '09 BLACK', 'colorNo': 'COL09'}, {'styleText': '12 PINK', 'colorNo': 'COL12'}, {'styleText': '31 BEIGE', 'colorNo': 'COL31'}, {'styleText': '34 BROWN', 'colorNo': 'COL34'}, {'styleText': '66 BLUE', 'colorNo': 'COL66'}, {'styleText': '69 NAVY', 'colorNo': 'COL69'}]               5     590.0                           HEATTECH 刷毛高領T恤 (長袖)     590.0  442063     3XL           Y      [EXTENDED SIZE]     LIST  女裝                           女裝 HEATTECH 刷毛高領T恤 (長袖) 442063      EXTENDED SIZE                   u0000000011100
12        590.0  4.5909        N  /hmall/test/u0000000009255/main/first/1000/1.jpg      XS     Y        Y         女裝      black                                                                                                                                     [{'styleText': '01 OFF WHITE', 'colorNo': 'COL01'}, {'styleText': '08 DARK GRAY', 'colorNo': 'COL08'}, {'styleText': '09 BLACK', 'colorNo': 'COL09'}, {'styleText': '30 NATURAL', 'colorNo': 'COL30'}, {'styleText': '32 BEIGE', 'colorNo': 'COL32'}]              22     590.0                                   華夫格圓領T恤 (長袖)     590.0  439067     3XL           Y      [EXTENDED SIZE]     LIST  女裝                                   女裝 華夫格圓領T恤 (長袖) 439067      EXTENDED SIZE                   u0000000009255
13        390.0    4.75        N                                               NaN      XS     Y        Y         女裝      black                                                                                     [{'styleText': '00 WHITE', 'colorNo': 'COL00'}, {'styleText': '02 LIGHT GRAY', 'colorNo': 'COL02'}, {'styleText': '09 BLACK', 'colorNo': 'COL09'}, {'styleText': '29 DARK ORANGE', 'colorNo': 'COL29'}, {'styleText': '47 YELLOW', 'colorNo': 'COL47'}, {'styleText': '69 NAVY', 'colorNo': 'COL69'}]              12     390.0                                 彈性柔滑棉圓領T恤 (長袖)     390.0  439062     3XL           Y      [EXTENDED SIZE]     LIST  女裝                                 女裝 彈性柔滑棉圓領T恤 (長袖) 439062      EXTENDED SIZE                   u0000000009304
14        390.0     5.0        N  /hmall/test/u0000000010162/main/first/1000/1.jpg       S     Y        Y         女裝      black                                                                                                                                                                                                 [{'styleText': '00 WHITE', 'colorNo': 'COL00'}, {'styleText': '07 GRAY', 'colorNo': 'COL07'}, {'styleText': '09 BLACK', 'colorNo': 'COL09'}, {'styleText': '17 RED', 'colorNo': 'COL17'}]               1     390.0                                彈性柔滑棉 高領T恤 (長袖)     390.0  439063     XXL           Y      [EXTENDED SIZE]     LIST  女裝                                女裝 彈性柔滑棉 高領T恤 (長袖) 439063      EXTENDED SIZE                   u0000000010162
15        590.0  4.8095        N                                               NaN       L     Y        Y         女裝        red                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                            [{'styleText': '00 WHITE', 'colorNo': 'COL00'}, {'styleText': '09 BLACK', 'colorNo': 'COL09'}]              21     390.0                                柔滑棉 設計下擺T恤 (長袖)     390.0  439065       L           Y  [concessional_rate]     LIST  女裝                                女裝 柔滑棉 設計下擺T恤 (長袖) 439065  concessional_rate                   u0000000009305
16        590.0   4.375        N                                               NaN      XS     Y        Y         女裝        red                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                         [{'styleText': '01 OFF WHITE', 'colorNo': 'COL01'}, {'styleText': '10 PINK', 'colorNo': 'COL10'}]              16     190.0                      棉質羅紋短版開襟外套 (長袖) (品牌好友穿著款)     190.0  446249     3XL           Y  [concessional_rate]     LIST  女裝                      女裝 棉質羅紋短版開襟外套 (長袖) (品牌好友穿著款) 446249  concessional_rate                   u0000000009409
17        390.0  4.1111        N  /hmall/test/u0000000009878/main/first/1000/1.jpg      XS     N        N         女裝        red                                                                                              [{'styleText': '00 WHITE', 'colorNo': 'COL00'}, {'styleText': '08 DARK GRAY', 'colorNo': 'COL08'}, {'styleText': '09 BLACK', 'colorNo': 'COL09'}, {'styleText': '12 PINK', 'colorNo': 'COL12'}, {'styleText': '31 BEIGE', 'colorNo': 'COL31'}, {'styleText': '66 BLUE', 'colorNo': 'COL66'}]               9     190.0                                    羅紋方領T恤 (長袖)     190.0  445628     3XL           Y  [concessional_rate]     LIST  女裝                                    女裝 羅紋方領T恤 (長袖) 445628  concessional_rate                   u0000000009878
18        790.0  4.6667        N  /hmall/test/u0000000008087/main/first/1000/1.jpg      XS     N        N         女裝        red                                                                                                                                                                                                                                          [{'styleText': '01 OFF WHITE', 'colorNo': 'COL01'}, {'styleText': '09 BLACK', 'colorNo': 'COL09'}, {'styleText': '18 WINE', 'colorNo': 'COL18'}]               6     390.0                                 喬其紗印花荷葉邊上衣(長袖)     390.0  443345     3XL           Y  [concessional_rate]   DELIST  女裝                                 女裝 喬其紗印花荷葉邊上衣(長袖) 443345  concessional_rate                   u0000000008087
19        790.0  4.3158        N  /hmall/test/u0000000008124/main/first/1000/1.jpg      XS     N        N         女裝        red                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                        [{'styleText': '01 OFF WHITE', 'colorNo': 'COL01'}, {'styleText': '09 BLACK', 'colorNo': 'COL09'}]              19     390.0                        印花V領澎袖上衣 (長袖) (品牌好友穿著款)     390.0  439736     3XL           Y  [concessional_rate]     LIST  女裝                        女裝 印花V領澎袖上衣 (長袖) (品牌好友穿著款) 439736  concessional_rate                   u0000000008124
20        790.0     3.8        N  /hmall/test/u0000000010858/main/first/1000/1.jpg      XS     Y        Y         女裝        red                                                                                                                                                 [{'styleText': '00 WHITE', 'colorNo': 'COL00'}, {'styleText': '04 GRAY', 'colorNo': 'COL04'}, {'styleText': '09 BLACK', 'colorNo': 'COL09'}, {'styleText': '11 PINK', 'colorNo': 'COL11'}, {'styleText': '55 GREEN', 'colorNo': 'COL55'}]               5     390.0                               Dry-EX 圓領T恤 (長袖)     390.0  442388     3XL           Y  [concessional_rate]     LIST  女裝                               女裝 Dry-EX 圓領T恤 (長袖) 442388  concessional_rate                   u0000000010858
```